# Understanding reinterpret_cast

Tags: c++, operator-keyword, reinterpret-cast

The following program runs without any issue, even though the memory allocated by the class `B` is not sufficient to host all the members of class `A`.

```
// CPP code to illustrate the pointer reinterpret
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A {
public:
    void fun_a()
    {
        cout << " In class A\n";
    }
    int Val;
    int Res;
};

class B {

};

int main()
{
    // creating object of class B
    B* x = new B();

    A* new_a = reinterpret_cast<A*>(x);

    // accessing the function of class A
    new_a->fun_a();
    new_a->Val = 10;
    new_a->Res = 20;

    cout << new_a->Val;
    cout << new_a->Res;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Undefined Behaviour includes appearing to work.  fyi: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub

Comment: `reinterpret_cast` basically means; just shut up compiler, I know what I'm doing, just treat this type as that other type and I'll accept the consequences. In *most* cases, using a `reinterpret_cast` is probably a bug. There are a few situations where you have to force the hand of the compiler and subvert the type system like that, but they are few and far between. And situations where you can do it in a well defined manner are even fewer. Reinterpret cast doesn't give you many guarantees beyond "you can cast foo to bar - if bar is large enough - and then you can cast bar back to foo".

Comment: the cases where `reinterpret_cast` is allowed are rather limited (see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast)). Only a single time I encountered a case where I thought I need it and it turned out that I was wrong (both in the sense that I didnt need it and in the sense that it wasnt allowed for what I used it)

Answer (score 5):

Indirecting through a pointer to `T` that doesn't point to an object of type `T` (or compatible type) results in undefined behaviour.

> The following program runs without any issue,

The program appearing to run without any issue is an example of undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Your code invokes *[Undefined Behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)* (UB), which means that it may work as you expected (for example, in your computer, today), but is *not* guaranteed.

You are correct that this code is not correct, and you are just (un)lucky that it "worked in your computer"!

Comment: Nitpicking: the program is not ill-formed.  Per [\[defns.well.formed\]](http://eel.is/c++draft/defns.well.formed), the program is well-formed because it is a C++ program constructed according to the syntax rules, diagnosable semantic rules, and the one-definition rule.  Per [\[defns.ill.formed\]](http://eel.is/c++draft/defns.ill.formed), the program is not ill-formed because it is well-formed.

Comment: @L.F. it didn't feel right when I wrote this, thanks for pointing that out, answer edited!

Answer (score 0):

It is undefined behavior. We should use reinterpret_cast when we know it is safe.
For example you want to send the object using socket programming. There, Api will take data as character buffer so there you can use it as
A* new_a = new A();
char* new_Data = reinterpret_cast(new_a);
At the receiving end you have to use invert operation using reinterpret_cast but this time from char * to A* ;
This is one scenario when you know it's safe.